# After input, println prints nothing out

Tags: java, io, println

I am making a game and it prompts you for your name and after you type in your name it asks you to confirm it by typing "N" or "Y". After pressing N it doesn't print anything back out although it does take in input but doesn't prompt you to do so as it doesn't print anything else. Only Y works. I have tried everything but it doesn't work.

This is the code I have done to confirm the name:

```
private static void comfirmName() {
    System.out.println("Is " + name +  " your name?");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    System.out.println("Y/N");

    if (input.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
        System.out.println("There is something you should know...");    
    }

    if (input.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("N")) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is " + name + " your name?");
    }

    if (!input.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("N") && !input.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter Y or N");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Welcome to Enchanted Mage!
Here we will venture into the dangers of this planet!
First of all, you must tell me your name, venturer!
Type in your name:
ots wng
Hello there ots wng!
Is ots wng your name?
Y/N
n
otswng
nothing is hapening
ummm
Please enter Y or N

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

There are no errors but it is really annoying to get any output out.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an input before entering the ifs, just like that:

```
String inputAnswer = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

and to be cleaner, just change the input.nextLine inside the ifs to the variable you just created, like that:

```
if(inputAnswer.equals("Y")){

    System.out.println("There is something you should know...");

}
```

I just tested that and it works. feel free to ask anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Read only once the confirmation.

```
private static void comfirmName() {
    System.out.println("Is " + name +  " your name?");

    System.out.println("Y/N");

    String confirmation = input.nextLine().toUpperCase(); //Read only once the user confirmation

    if (confirmation.equals("Y")) {
        System.out.println("There is something you should know...");
    }

    if (confirmation.equals("N")) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is " + name + " your name?");
    }

    if (!confirmation.equals("N") && !confirmation.equals("Y")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter Y or N");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Is Dan your name?
Y/N
n
Enter your name:
Dan
Is Dan your name?
```